# Effect of log4j vulnerability on wildfly-11.0.0-final

Tags: security, jboss, log4j, wildfly, wildfly-11

I am using wildfly-11.0.0-final. I can see the log4j-jboss-logmanager jar has a log4j 1.2.16 dependency. Will it be affected? How to mitigate this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using the JMSAppender you shouldn't be exposed if I understand https://www.wildfly.org/news/2021/12/13/Log4j-CVEs/ correctly.